# Зацикливание Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular4, angular5

building.service.ts

```
getAll(): Observable<BuildingModel[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.config.buildings);
  }
```

building.component.ts

```
  getBuildings(){
    this.buildingService.getAll().subscribe(buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
return this.buildings;
  }
```

building.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let building of getBuildings()">
  <p>{{building.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Начинает зацикливаться вызов бэка, если в ngFor получать массив с помощью метода getBuildings. Но если делать через ngOnInit работает отлично. Почему происходит зацикливание?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в функции:

```
getBuildings(){
    this.buildingService.getAll().subscribe(buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
    return this.buildings;
}
```

Данная функция вызывается при каждом цикле получения изменений. Сделайте следующим образом:

```
 <div *ngFor="let building of this.buildings">
     <p>{{building.name}}</p>
 </div>
```

А функцию `getBuildings` уже в удобном для Вас месте, переписав её следующим образом:

```
getBuildings(){
    this.buildingService.getAll().subscribe(buildings => this.buildings = buildings);
}
```

Comment: `return` не нужен

Answer (score 0):

building.service.ts - оставляем как есть

```
getAll(): Observable<BuildingModel[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.config.buildings);
  }
```

building.component.ts - меняем

```
  buildings$: Observable<BuildingModel[]>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildings$ = this.buildingService.getAll();
  }
```

building.component.html - меняем

```
<div *ngFor="let building of (buildings$ | async)">
  <p>{{building.name}}</p>
</div>
```

- дополнительный положительный эффект, не нужно подписываться и отписываться.

Comment: зачем делать http вызов в `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Здесь не происходит вызова, здесь происходит создание ссылки на объект `Observable`, вызов происходит уже с помощью `AsyncPipe` при выводе данных на странице.

Comment: нет, вопрос относился к тому почему данную операцию нужно делать в `ngOnInit` а не в конструкторе?

Comment: конструктор это конструктор. ngOnInit() не аналогичен конструктору. Конструктор также может выполнять некоторую инициализацию объекта, в то же время что-то сложное в конструкторе делать не рекомендуется. Конструктор должен быть по возможности простым и выполнять самую базовую инициализацию. Что-то более сложное, например, загрузку данных с сервера, которая может занять продолжительное время, лучше делать в методе ngOnInit.
https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.8.php

Comment: что изменится если Вы перенесете это операцию в конструктор?

Comment: Конструктор вызывается при создании дерево компонентов.

Comment: Вы понимаете разницу между `constructor` и `ngOnInit` и для чего вообще используется `ngOnInit`, и как Angular инициализирует компоненты?

Comment: Конструктор вызывается при создании дерево компонентов. `ngOnInit()` вызывается в фазе обнаружения изменений. Например из существенного, если нужно использовать параметры `@Input` то их вы сможете отработать, только в `ngOnInit()`, а зависимости компонента разрешаются в конструкторе, он так там и называется `constructor injection pattern`.  
И всегда хорошей практикой считается как можно меньше логики в конструктор, а логику жизненного цикла использовать в хуках, например в `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Конструктор не вызывается при создании дерева, дерево это просто высокоуровневая абстракция, вся инициализация `View` разруливается через `ComponentFactoryResolver`, который преобразовывает конструктор в фабрику (`instanceof ComponentFactory`), далее в дело вступает синглтон `Services` который содержит метод `createComponentView` и вызывается в цикле методом `createViewNodes`, там идет проверка на то - нужно ли вызывать фабрику компонента (допустим он находится на нужном роуте и в нужном шаблоне). Такая практика не распространяется на `js`, советую Вам почитать `performance checklist` в `V8`

Comment: Брррр.... Вы о чем вообще? 
Читайте документацию:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence
или конкретно, в чем разница constructor vs NgOnInit, а в частности, там же есть пояснение в чем разница, конструктора в JS и в TS.
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-how-to-get-viewcontainerref-before-viewchild-query-is-evaluated-f649e51315fb

Comment: Вы перепрыгнули с темы на тему. Речь шла о разнице `ngOnInit` и `constructor`, Вы сказали `Конструктор вызывается при создании дерево компонентов. `, я Вам ответил, что это не так, теперь Вы переспрашиваете `Вы о чем вообще?`. `ngOnInit` вызывается в методе `checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline` ПОСЛЕ проверки на байндинги методом `checkBinding`, а еще точнее если `prototype` компонента имеет метод `ngOnInit`, это проверяется в `shouldCallLifecycleInitHook`. И еще не понял вопроса по `разница конструктора в JS и TS`? :) `constructor` это синтаксический сахар поверх `FunctionDeclaration`, неважно где.

Comment: По моему это Вы прыгаете с одного на другое: первоначальный Ваш вопрос, был "зачем делать http вызов в ngOnInit?" Не зная реализации компонента ТС, Вам почему то хочется впихнуть его в конструктор, хотя логичнее и правильнее, ТС посоветовать именно `ngOnInit`. 
И теперь вопрос, как поможет Ваш словесный понос про внутреннею реализацию механизма инициализации компонента ТС и любому другом, кто зайдет на данный вопрос?

Comment: :)) что значит `ТС посоветовать именно ngOnInit`?

Comment: как бы Вам помягче ответить. У человека бек зацикливается, и неизвестно, что у него и как в других местах. Так, что вызов будет `ngOnInit` однозначно тогда когда все точно проинициализировано, и не будет у ТС новых проблем.

Comment: Вы говорите про инициализацию, в `ngOnInit` просто уже доступен определенный список декорируемых свойств типа `@Input / @ViewChild etc`, если есть зависимость от байндингов - то, конечно уместен только `ngOnInit`, а в остальных случаях  - конструктор.

Comment: Еще раз читаем официальную документацию до просветления [OnInit()](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit)
_Experienced developers agree that components should be cheap and safe to construct._ и _Don't fetch data in a component constructor._

Comment: Не учите людей плохому.

Comment: Никто никому не учит плохому, там есть ссылка на http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/, я могу согласиться на то, что в конструкторе нельзя писать тяжелые синхронные операции, как пример пройтись по массиву из 1000 элементов, сделать проверку через `if` + еще что-то и тд., но когда мы делаем какую-то асинхронную операцию - можно поспорить, любой http запрос не лочит главный поток, а теперь сами задумайтесь - где в данном случае конструктор становится не `cheap and safe`?